# Algorithm to calculate the minimum bill amount based on Deals

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to develop a program in java where I need to calculate the minimum bill for given item.

The standard price per item is as follows:
Onion- Rs.5
Tomato- Rs.10
Potato - Rs.2

There is one more list with different deals for the items. One item can have more than one deal.

2 Onion - Rs.7.5
3 Onion - Rs.10

3 Tomato - Rs.25
5 Tomato - Rs.45

3 Potato - Rs.5
4 Potato - Rs. 6.5

And it can have more.
So the method needs to calculate the bill amount in such a way that for any given quantity (considering the given deals) it should give the minimum bill amount.

Input will be in following format The program should calculate the minimum amount to be paid :-

onion,tomato,onion,potato,tomato,onion,onion

```
(4)onion -> (10+5)  
(2)tomato -> (10*2)  
(1)potato -> 2  
------------------
minimum bill -> 37
```

I have two class, one named vegetable & other named Deal as below

```
public class Deal {

    private String code;
    private String quantity;
    private String price;

    //getters & setters         
}



public class Vegetable{

private String code;
private String name;
private String price;

//getters & setters 
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem? Or do you just look for someone to do your homework for you?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this is the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem). Just consider the total number as the volume of the knapsack and 1 divided by the price of each item as it's value.

Example:

(4)onion         -> W = 4
items:
2 Onion - Rs.7.5 -> w = 2, value = 1/7.5
3 Onion - Rs.10  -> w = 3, value = 1/10

Note: solve this problem for each item separately.

BTW, there are many source codes available on the internet like [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/96optimization/Knapsack.java.html), nevertheless I suggest you to try yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do the whole thing for you but this is what this algorithm could look like:

```
public int getPrice(int code)
{
    int price = getVegetableBasePrice(code);
    Iterator<Deal> it = deals.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        Deal next = it.next();
        if(next.getCode() == code)
        {
            price = Math.min(price, deal.getPrice());
        }
    }

    return price;
}
```

It would be much better to calculate all of the prices of all of the items at one time, because this will cause polynomial time complexity when you can achieve this with linear time. It depends how good you need the algorithm to be.